# How to resize only particular view when keyboard is shown

Tags: android, android-softkeyboard

I've got an Activity with FrameLayout which holds two views.

Currently, when the keyboard becomes visible **both views are resized**.

Is it possible to resize **only one** of these views and keep the size of old one?